# Ionic 4 IOS platform Send SMS without opening SMS app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, sms

I am using Ionic 4 and l have managed to send an SMS without using the SMS application on ANDROID now i want to implement this on IOS platform and l have done it and it keeps on opening the SMS application.

The reason l want to send SMS in the background is because when you tap an alert button it makes a call and at the same time send SMS in the background with the users current location.

IOS is giving SMS view and call screens at the same time.

Your assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should send SMS via server side not from users Mobile. If what user have no credit in his mobile then sms will not be send and your use case will get messed up. Secondly there is security and privacy issue. i doubt Apple will not approve your application.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, so i have to use an api for sending SMS like buying sms?.

Comment: Yes. You can check firebase for sending sms.

Comment: It is a privacy restriction on iOS. You cannot send a text message, from the user's number without them seeing the message and having the opportunity to edit or cancel the message.  You can use a service, such as Twilio, to send a text message from your own number via an api.